# Exibir caminho do mp3 ao invés de fazer download

Tags: php

Olá. Tenho uma classe no meu projeto que junta vários arquivos de áudio e me devolvem um outro mp3 com todos esses arquivos em um só o download começa automaticamente (sem necessitar do usuário clicar em nada).

Existe alguma forma de eu conseguir fazer esse arquivo tocar ao invés de fazer o download?

Classe:

```
<?php
// This is the class to generate mp3 files based on the anti-spam words
// Based on the PHP mp3 class at http://www.sourcerally.net/Scripts/20-PHP-MP3-Class
// Output code based on the FPDF class at http://www.fpdf.org
class mp3
  {
    var $str;
    var $time;
    var $frames;

    // Create a new mp3
    function mp3($path="")
    {
    if($path!="")
        {
        $this->str = file_get_contents($path);
        }
    }

  // Put an mp3 behind the first mp3
  function mergeBehind($mp3)
  {
  $this->str .= $mp3->str;
  }

  // Calculate where's the end of the sound file
  function getIdvEnd()
  {
  $strlen = strlen($this->str);
  $str = substr($this->str,($strlen-128));
  $str1 = substr($str,0,3);
  if(strtolower($str1) == strtolower('TAG'))
  {
  return $str;
  }
  else
  {
  return false;
  }
  }

  // Calculate where's the beginning of the sound file
  function getStart()
  {
  $strlen = strlen($this->str);
  for($i=0;$i<$strlen;$i++)
  {
  $v = substr($this->str,$i,1);
  $value = ord($v);
  if($value == 255)
  {
  return $i;
  }
  }
  }

  // Remove the ID3 tags
  function striptags()
  {
  //Remove start stuff...
  $newStr = '';
  $s = $start = $this->getStart();
  if($s===false)
  {
  return false;
  }
  else
  {
  $this->str = substr($this->str,$start);
  }
  //Remove end tag stuff
  $end = $this->getIdvEnd();
  if($end!==false)
  {
  $this->str = substr($this->str,0,(strlen($this->str)-129));
  }
  }

  // Display an error
  function error($msg)
  {
  //Fatal error
  die('<strong>audio file error: </strong>'.$msg);
  }

 // Send the new mp3 to the browser
  function output($path)
  {
  //Output mp3
  //Send to standard output
  if(ob_get_contents())
  $this->error('Some data has already been output, can\'t send mp3 file');
  if(php_sapi_name()!='cli')
  {
  //We send to a browser
  header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg3');
  if(headers_sent())
  $this->error('Some data has already been output to browser, can\'t send mp3 file');
  header('Content-Length: '.strlen($this->str));
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$path.'"');
  }
  echo $this->str;
  return '';
  }
  }
  ?>
```

Usando:

```
// Specify the word 
$petersword = "testword";

$word_count = strlen($petersword);

 // Set up the first file
  if ($word_count > 0) {
  $mp3 = new mp3($cas_fontpath . 'sounds/' . substr($petersword, 0, 1) . '.mp3');
  $mp3->striptags();
  }

// Generate the mp3 file from each letter in the word 
  for ($i = 1; $i < $word_count; ++$i) {
  $cas_character = $cas_fontpath . 'sounds/' . substr($petersword, $i, 1);
  $cas_mp3equivalent = new mp3($cas_character . '.mp3');
  $mp3->mergeBehind($cas_mp3equivalent);
  $mp3->striptags();
  }

  // Spit out the audio file!  
$mp3->output('word.mp3');
```

Comment: Se entendi, você quer que na hora de clicar no link ele não baixe o arquivo, mas sim abra o player do computador (o que é possivel) ou toque diretamente na página, é isto?

Comment: Exatamente, mas o problema é que eu não onde conseguir um caminho pra esse arquivo tocar.

Comment: Aonde é salvo o arquivo? Poderia fornecer um exemplo?

Comment: A classe chama uma função chamada output e o download começa

Comment: http://www.theblog.ca/merge-mp3s-php Essa classe que eu to usando

Comment: Permita-me editar a sua pergunta, pois o contexto dela está fora do contexto da sua duvida real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remova isto do seu código `$mp3->output('word.mp3');` e na classe você pode adicionar um novo metodo, neste metodo você terá que manipular a variavel `$this->str`, seria algo como:

```
class mp3 {
...
    function save($path) {
       file_put_contents($path, $this->str);
    }
}
```

O seu código deve ficar assim:

```
// Specify the word 
$petersword = "testword";

$word_count = strlen($petersword);

 // Set up the first file
  if ($word_count > 0) {
  $mp3 = new mp3($cas_fontpath . 'sounds/' . substr($petersword, 0, 1) . '.mp3');
  $mp3->striptags();
  }

// Generate the mp3 file from each letter in the word 
  for ($i = 1; $i < $word_count; ++$i) {
  $cas_character = $cas_fontpath . 'sounds/' . substr($petersword, $i, 1);
  $cas_mp3equivalent = new mp3($cas_character . '.mp3');
  $mp3->mergeBehind($cas_mp3equivalent);
  $mp3->striptags();
  }

//Salva o arquivo
$mp3->save('/var/www/projetc1/static/sounds/word.mp3');
```

E para exibir você terá que pegar o caminho virtual da pasta `static/sounds` (é apenas um exemplo) que seria algo como:

```
http://localhost/projetc1/static/sounds/word.mp3
```

Então você decide o caminho que quer que o arquivo seja salvo :)

Answer (score 2):

Você poderia usar a tag html `<audio>`

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Ou alguma API feita em JQuery que reproduza o áudio.